# Вывод списка объектов на страницу react приложения

Tags: javascript, массивы, reactjs

Имеется массив:

```
[
    {
        "bets": {
            "0": {
                "odds": "1.44",
                "match": "mc - mu",
                "id": 0,
                "market": "goal"
            },
            "1": {
                "market": "corner",
                "match": "Torpedo - Pobeda",
                "odds": "2.05",
                "id": 1
            }
        },
        "id": "cepNnANcuoV368WH8VrF"
    }
]
```

Необходимо вывести список значений ключей market. Подскажите, что делаю не так?

```
const betsOdds = [...new Set(массив.map(el => el.bets))];

    return (
            <ul> 
             {betsOdds.map((bet)=>(
                <li key={bet.id}>{bet.market}</li>
             )
             )}
            </ul> 
    );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы из вашего массива достаете объект **bets** и его кладете в **betsOdds** как элемент массива. А у **bets** нет ключа **market**

Надо для каждого элемента **bets** пробегаться циклом и вытаскивать данные.

```
const betsOdds = []
arr.forEach(el => {
  for (let i in el.bets) {
    if (!betsOdds.find(it => el.bets[i].market === it.market))
    betsOdds.push(el.bets[i])
  }
})
```

```js
const arr = [
    {
        "bets": {
            "0": {
                "odds": "1.44",
                "match": "mc - mu",
                "id": 0,
                "market": "goal"
            },
            "1": {
                "market": "corner",
                "match": "Torpedo - Pobeda",
                "odds": "2.05",
                "id": 1
            }
        },
        "id": "cepNnANcuoV368WH8VrF"
    },
    {
        "bets": {
            "0": {
                "odds": "1.44",
                "match": "mc - mu",
                "id": 0,
                "market": "goal"
            },
            "1": {
                "market": "street",
                "match": "Torpedo - Pobeda",
                "odds": "2.05",
                "id": 1
            }
        },
        "id": "cepNnANcuoV368WH8VrF"
    }
];

const betsOdds = []
arr.forEach(el => {
  for (let i in el.bets) {
    if (!betsOdds.find(it => el.bets[i].market === it.market))
    betsOdds.push(el.bets[i])
  }
})

console.log(betsOdds)
```

Вот такой массив уже сможете отрендерить